# HTML tidy linter: <button> in <span> errors

Tags: html, tidy, htmltidy

I'm using tidy 5.2.0.

The following works fine and shows no tidy linting errors:

```
<button type  = "button" class = "btn btn-default">  
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>  
</button>
```

However, if I place the button in a span tag, tidy shows 3 errors:

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type  = "button" class = "btn btn-default">  
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>  
    </button>
</span>

Error 1: missing </button>
Error 2: inserting implicit <span>
Error 3: replacing unexpected button with </button>
```

Comment: Most likely something to do with the HTML spec saying nothing other than text should be inside a `<button>`

Comment: Thanks - so I assume I can ignore the issue. Perhaps I'll add it to SublimeLinter ignore_match settings

Comment: I suppose so, but be careful as some browsers do get messy with things inside buttons. Maybe use a class and inject the glyphicon via css `:before`

Comment: What if you change from `span` to `div`?

Comment: changing to div tag does help - thanks - although still not sure why it was an issue in the first place

Comment: Maybe because span is an inline element, and button is inline-block?